# Navigation Bar on Immersive Mode isn't translucent

Tags: android

I'm using the Fullscreen Activity provided by Android Studio, but the Navigation Bar isn't translucent, it always shows a white or black background.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJqlI.png)

Anyone knows whats the problem here?

Edit -

I solved my problem deleting all the code gives by the android studio and putting this:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus){
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you have done to make it full screen.
Did you try,

`View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);`

Comment: I've changed nothing, it's just the code generated by the android studio

Comment: By default the Android Studio code isn't translucent?

Comment: On full screen activity it hides the navigation. If its not you might have mess with the theme or style.xml